# How many "$Q$-like" sentences are there?

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, lattice-orders, proof-theory

Call a sentence $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic **$Q$-like** iff $\mathbb{N}\models\varphi$ and $\{\varphi\}$ is essentially incomplete (= no computably axiomatizable theory containing $\varphi$ is complete and consistent). The standard example is the conjunction of the finitely many axioms of [Robinson's $Q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) (hence the name), but this is of course not unique - and indeed the partial order $\mathfrak{Q}$ of (equivalence classes of) $Q$-like sentences under entailment is not linear. On the positive side, $\mathfrak{Q}$ is clearly a distributive lattice.

My question is:

> What exactly is $\mathfrak{Q}$, up to isomorphism?

There's an obvious candidate, based on the idea that everything that can happen does in this sort of situation: the **(countable) random distributive lattice** (that is, the Fraisse limit of the set of finite distributive lattices - see e.g. [here](http://pages.mini.pw.edu.pl/aaa88/Slides/Masulovic.pdf)). However, I'm having trouble proving this. Even showing that $\mathfrak{Q}$ has no least element isn't trivial, as far as I can see.

(As a quick remark, note that essentially undecidable theories need not come from elements of $\mathfrak{Q}$: Robinson's $R$ is essentially undecidable but each of its finitely axiomatizable subtheories has a computable completion, since each such theory is satisfied in (an appropriate analogue of) $\mathbb{N}_{\le k}\cup\mathbb{R}_{>k}$ for some integer $k$ which is decidable since it's interpretable in [a decidable structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Decidability_and_quantifier_elimination). So this is a bit more finicky than understanding the simpler class of essentially undecidable theories.)

Comment: If $\phi$ is Q-like, isn't it the case that there is a sentence $\psi$ of $Th(\Bbb N)$ that is not a consequence of $\phi$? Then $\phi\land\psi$ would be Q-like and below $\phi$ in the lattice.

Comment: @zarathustra No - since $\phi\wedge\psi\vdash\phi$, we have that $\phi\wedge\psi$ is *above* $\phi$ in the lattice.

Comment: Ok, I was just looking at it upside down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fedor Pakhomov showed at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359268/8133) that $\mathfrak{Q}$ is in fact the countable random distributive lattice.

*(I've made this CW to avoid reputation gain, and will delete this answer if Fedor posts an answer of his own here.)*